# Using NgClass and ternary expressions inside ListView and RadListView templates

Tags: nativescript

Is using `[ngClass]` and ternary expressions, the same as using `*ngIf` in terms of hurting the recycling process of elements in ListView and RadListView?
Suppose I have a `Label` that should sometimes show "missing" text, in the color of red, and sometimes just show other text in black.
What's the most efficient way to show this in NativeScript?

*Option #1:*

1. Getting some data from the backend with a boolean flag, suggesting
   some element should have the red "missing".
2. Inside a template in the HTML, conditioning the text color css class with the boolean.
3. Inside the HTML, conditioning the word "missing" with a ternary expression.

Example: 
`<Label [text]="!item.isMissing ? item.title : 'missing'" [ngClass]="{'missing-text': item.isMissing, 'regular-text': !item.isMissing}"></Label>`

*Option #2:*

1. Getting some data from the backend with a boolean flag, suggesting
   some element should have the red "missing".
2. Using template selector and create a template (marked A) that has a red "missing" text.
3. creating a different template (marked B) for all other elements that are displayed regularly.

Example for the Label in template A:
`<Label text="missing" class="missing-text"></Label>`
and for the Label in template B:
`<Label [text]="item.title" class="regular-text"></Label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 works but Option #2 is comparatively more efficient as it wouldn't have to update styles while recycling.